# Deploying a Maven project to Tomcat fails to connect to Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm trying to import a .war file to tomcat8.

So far, even if Tomcat is started I can't access my web app's page.
And i get this error from this command (`systemctl status tomcat8.service`) :

```
Mar 11 11:34:25 osboxes tomcat8[48213]:     at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:404)
Mar 11 11:34:25 osboxes tomcat8[48213]:     at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:272)
Mar 11 11:34:25 osboxes tomcat8[48213]:     at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnect
Mar 11 11:34:25 osboxes tomcat8[48213]:     at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectio
Mar 11 11:34:25 osboxes tomcat8[48213]:     at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSou
Mar 11 11:34:25 osboxes tomcat8[48213]:     at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicD
Mar 11 11:34:25 osboxes tomcat8[48213]:     ... 27 more
Mar 11 11:34:25 osboxes tomcat8[48213]: Starting service [Catalina]
Mar 11 11:34:25 osboxes tomcat8[48213]: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.34 (Ubuntu)
Mar 11 11:34:25 osboxes tomcat8[48213]: Deploying web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/slb.war]
```

And couples seconds later :

```
Mar 11 11:25:02 osboxes tomcat8[47998]:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
Mar 11 11:25:02 osboxes tomcat8[47998]:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
Mar 11 11:25:02 osboxes tomcat8[47998]:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
Mar 11 11:25:02 osboxes tomcat8[47998]:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Mar 11 11:25:02 osboxes tomcat8[47998]: Deployment of web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/slb.war] has finished in [
Mar 11 11:25:02 osboxes tomcat8[47998]: Deploying web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT]
Mar 11 11:25:02 osboxes tomcat8[47998]: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this
Mar 11 11:25:02 osboxes tomcat8[47998]: Deployment of web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [3
Mar 11 11:25:02 osboxes tomcat8[47998]: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 11 11:25:02 osboxes tomcat8[47998]: Server startup in 7238 ms
```

And by the way the lines with the driver are highlighted in red.

**Content of tomcat libs :**

```
osboxes@osboxes:~/hds-api-master$ 
ls /var/lib/tomcat8/lib/
–p  postgresql-9.4.1212.jar
```

**Where I come from** :

I exported a java spring boot app to a .war extension without an error and got a .war and moved it to tomcat's web apps folder.
Commands I used for maven :

```
mvn clean install
mvn package
```

**What it's supposed to do:** 
Open a web server on port 8080 with the URL :

> localhost:8080/slb

**EDIT :** 
I changed the passwords in the conf file and now my tomcat server is running fine apparently, but apparently i can't access my webapp or maybe i'm doing it wrong, here's the logs :

**Systemctl;**

```
tomcat8.service - Apache Tomcat 8.5 Web Application Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tomcat8.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-03-12 04:57:57 EDT; 2min 33s ago
     Docs: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/index.html
  Process: 59566 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/tomcat8/tomcat-update-policy.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 59582 (java)
    Tasks: 34 (limit: 4653)
   Memory: 363.9M
   CGroup: /system.slice/tomcat8.service
           â””â”€59582 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64//bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat8/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /usr/share/tomcat8/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat8 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

Mar 12 04:58:07 osboxes tomcat8[59582]: 2019-03-12 04:58:07 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
Mar 12 04:58:08 osboxes tomcat8[59582]: 2019-03-12 04:58:08 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Mar 12 04:58:10 osboxes tomcat8[59582]: 2019-03-12 04:58:10 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
Mar 12 04:58:10 osboxes tomcat8[59582]: 2019-03-12 04:58:10 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  fr.thuasne.slb.hds.api.Application - Started Application in 8.473 seconds (JVM running for 12.378)
Mar 12 04:58:10 osboxes tomcat8[59582]: Deployment of web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/slb.war] has finished in [11,978] ms
Mar 12 04:58:10 osboxes tomcat8[59582]: Deploying web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT]
Mar 12 04:58:11 osboxes tomcat8[59582]: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 12 04:58:11 osboxes tomcat8[59582]: Deployment of web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [398] ms
Mar 12 04:58:11 osboxes tomcat8[59582]: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 12 04:58:11 osboxes tomcat8[59582]: Server startup in 12692 ms
```

**And the tomcat log file :**

```
12-Mar-2019 04:57:57.874 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
12-Mar-2019 04:57:57.878 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
12-Mar-2019 04:57:57.878 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
12-Mar-2019 04:57:57.879 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
12-Mar-2019 04:57:57.880 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
12-Mar-2019 04:57:57.881 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
12-Mar-2019 04:57:57.881 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
12-Mar-2019 04:57:57.881 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
12-Mar-2019 04:57:57.881 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
12-Mar-2019 04:57:57.882 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
12-Mar-2019 04:57:57.882 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
12-Mar-2019 04:57:57.882 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.451 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.34 (Ubuntu)
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.453 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 20 2018 08:12:50 UTC
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.454 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.34.0
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.455 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.455 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.18.0-10-generic
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.456 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.457 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.458 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1-b12
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.460 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.461 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /var/lib/tomcat8
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.462 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/share/tomcat8
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.463 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat8/conf/logging.properties
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.465 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.466 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms512m
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.466 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx1024m
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.467 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.468 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.469 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.469 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.470 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.471 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat8
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.471 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat8
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.473 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.473 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.17] using APR version [1.6.3].
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.474 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.480 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018]
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.649 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.668 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.683 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 774 ms
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.938 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.940 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.34 (Ubuntu)
12-Mar-2019 04:57:58.976 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/slb.war]
12-Mar-2019 04:58:01.308 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
12-Mar-2019 04:58:10.956 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/slb.war] has finished in [11,978] ms
12-Mar-2019 04:58:10.957 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT]
12-Mar-2019 04:58:11.351 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
12-Mar-2019 04:58:11.355 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [398] ms
12-Mar-2019 04:58:11.364 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
12-Mar-2019 04:58:11.376 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 12692 ms
```

**SOLVED :**

For the last problem , i needed to access tomcat with http://127.0.0.1:8080/ not localhost

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Please post the beginning of the exception information in the logs.  You posted from the middle.

Comment: I adde the beginning of the logs :)

Comment: You added the logs from Systemd, but they only include the last 10 lines or so from Tomcat.  Find the Tomcat logs and post the exception information from there.

Comment: I updated the title since this is does not seem to be a Driver issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from your post what is the issue exactly because you posted only part of the exception.  The log entries you posted are from Systemd, which only include a portion of the Tomcat logs.  Find the Tomcat logs, by default in `$CATALINA_BASE/logs`.

If the problem is indeed with a missing driver, you can confirm that by copying the driver to the `$CATALINA_BASE/lib` directory - restart Tomcat for the changes to take effect.

If that is indeed the case and you want to deploy the PG-JDBC jar with your app then there are different ways to do so with Maven, e.g. the [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html), or add it to the resource directory and use Maven [maven-resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html).

Comment: I found the error inside the catalina log file of tomcat : 
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "xxxxx")
I'll try to fix it and come back to you, but thanks to you i manage to find the cause of the error !

Comment: @Quentin_otd - Great!  Make sure that the username/password are correct, and that the client IP is allowed in Postgres' configuration file `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: Okey it was definitively the password and i fixed it in the conf files and now my server is running fine, i guess ?
But i still can't access my webapp, i'm still a beginner with tomcat so maybe i'm doing it wrong ?
I'll post the logs in the question above, but thanks a lot so far !

Comment: For accessing tomcat i needed to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost ! thanks a lot again